# Using drawRect with variable width as a bar graph

Tags: android

I am creating a program in Android for work that takes numeric input from getText fields that represent hourly production.  As data is entered into the getText fields, I want to have a Drawable rectangle that will fill to and change colors to represent total production as a percentage of the production goal.

What is the best method to achieve a graphical representation of six machine production counts?  I am trying to draw an independent horizontal bar for each machine that I can insert into the xml layout I have already created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create TextViews for graphical representation of each machine production counts. Calculate the width of individual textviews as (device width available) * (current production) / (production goal)
Using setBackgroundResource you can set different colors/images depending upon width.
There may be other ways, but this is how i did it and this is definitely better than using chart libraries if you don't want extra features.

Comment: I originally had used textviews for the graphs, but I changed course when I realized that xml does not take variable input... how would I go about using variables to define the size of my textview?

Comment: can you use the setWidth() method of TextView to set the size dynamically. declare the  android:id="@+id/exampleTextView" of the textview and  TextView exampleTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.exampleTextView);
exampleTextView.setWidth(PercentageValue);

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [library](https://bitbucket.org/danielnadeau/holographlibrary/wiki/Home). You can then convert the string from the edittext into either a double or int to place into the HoloGraph Library.